# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Redirect HTTPS Non www to HTTPS WWW

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Let us use `example.com` for my situation. I have deployed an Elastic Beanstalk application. Within the application, I have modified the EC2 Application Load Balancers, to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS traffic.

In Route 53 this is my current configuration

```
Name               Type     Value
example.com.       A        ALIAS www.example.com.
example.com.       NS       4 aws name servers
example.com.       SOA      Values provided by Amazon
www.example.com.   A        ALIAS elastic beanstalk url
```

Under this configuration http://example.com --> https://example.com and http://www.example.com --> https://www.example.com

Instead, how do I have the configuration to be https://example.com --> https://www.example.com or http://example.com --> https://www.example.com ?

Comment: Your configuration should already work as expected. Can you describe why it does not work? Any errors or timeouts?

Comment: I fixed the issue. It had something to do with the Application Load Balancer (ALB) settings. I've modified the rules to specifically redirect to `https://www.example.com:443/#{path}?#{query}` in both HTTP: 80 and HTTPS: 443 listeners.

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for letting me know.